# Как решить проблемы с высоким I\O при чтении сервером файлов >100мб?

Tags: php, io, hosting

Понадобилось через компонент MODX импортировать 10 150-190 мб файлы, но, как я узнал, импорт крашится из-за резкого превышения лимита i\o(2.5мб в секунд на хостинге)

Пробовал увеличить эти параметры

```
php_value max_execution_time 86400 (любое значение не работает)
php_value max_input_time 86400(любое значение не работает)
php_value upload_max_filesize 2000M(200M не работает)
php_value post_max_size 2000M(200M не работает)
php_value memory_limit 1024M(128-2048 не работает)
```

Но это ничем не помогло.

Время ожидать импорт есть, но разделить файлы меньше чем на 150 мб не могу, иначе сам процесс импорта будет слишком долгим.

Вопрос: Можно ли лимитировать I\O на хостинге или в целом решить проблему с ним, что бы можно было стабильно без ошибок импортировать файл?

Компонент - Catalogfill.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/345024/ если подумать - в статье ответ есть =)

Comment: Если бы это был vps, то думаю подошло бы. Но я не знаю, как собственно это реализовать на стороне сервера, что бы все работало. Сижу на shared hosting и доступ есть только к php.ini и .htaccess

Comment: Вы статью то прочитайте, там описано КАК читать файл КУСКАМИ а не целиком =) прочитали кусок, подождали, прочитали следующий кусок, и т.д.... и I\O не будет вырастать до критичных значений.

Comment: Я имею ввиду то что я не знаю куда этот код в cpanel вставлять, ищу ищу а конкретно варианта не нахожу =(

Если знаете, то подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Если вы хотите вставить код из примеров по ссылке в CPanel то ваш вариант - биржа фрилансеров.